# 文字列で返されたハッシュ内の最大値を検索したい

Tags: ruby

```
hash = {"1"=>"53.0", "3"=>"50.30", "5"=>"1.600", "7"=>"63.0", "9"=>"103.400"}
```

上記のような場合にvalueの最大値103.400を検索し、そのkeyの"9"を出力したいのですが上手くいきません。

以下のようにvalueを文字列から数値にしてmaxを求めてその値を検索すればいいかと思いましたが上手くいかずnilが返ってきます。

```
hash = {"1"=>"53.0", "3"=>"50.30", "5"=>"1.600", "7"=>"63.0", "9"=>"103.400"}
p hash1 = hash.values.map(&:to_f)
p a = hash1.max.to_s
p hash.find{|k,v| v == a }
```

小数点以下の0の表記が問題なのかなと思いますが、求め方自体が無理やり感があるような気がします。
他にも何か求め方があれば教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: [この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040733)を参考に、`hash.max_by{|k, v| v.to_f}[0]` など。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_f` → `to_s` することで、存在しない文字列 `"103.4"` (文字列としての `"103.400"` と `"103.4"` は異なる) を探すことになってしまっていますね。

```
hash.max_by {|k,v| v.to_f}
```

で、値が最大であるキーとその値のペアが配列として返りますので、その1要素目が望みの値となります。

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {"1"=>"53.0", "3"=>"50.30", "5"=>"1.600", "7"=>"63.0", "9"=>"103.400"}
p hash1 = hash.values.map(&:to_f)
p a = hash1.max
p hash.find{|k,v| v.to_f === a }
```

そのコードで`["9", "103.400"]`が出力しています。keyが出力したいなら、以下のコードを使ってください。

```
hash = {"1"=>"53.0", "3"=>"50.30", "5"=>"1.600", "7"=>"63.0", "9"=>"103.400"}
p hash1 = hash.values.map(&:to_f)
p a = hash1.max
p result = hash.find{|k,v| v.to_f === a }
p result[0]
```